# Add column to a data frame with output of a function from input values of that data frame

Tags: r, function, dataframe

I have a data frame with 4 columns. I want to add a fith column with values from a function that uses the values of the row in in data frame as an input.

I have tried the following for example...

```
my.function <-(input1,input2,input3){
random = sample(10:200,1)
if((input1>=5) & (input2>=15) & (input3>=35)){
(input1 * input2 * input3) + random
}else{
(input1+input2+input3) + random
}

}
}

my.frame <- (1:10,11:20,21:30,31:40)
my.frame$new.col <- my.function(my.frame[,1],my.frame[,2],my.frame[,3])
```

...but this does not work.

What am I doing wrong?

*EDIT: I have added an example for the function. It should now be reproducible.*

Comment: I don't see a reproducible example, so I can offer only guesses. Possibly you want `mapply`.

Comment: I am not sure if I want apply at all.

`my.frame$new.col <- my.function(my.frame[,1],my.frame[,2],my.frame[,2])` returns a warning message from my function that does not appear when using in in other instances.

`In if ((input1 >= numeric_value1) & (input2 >= numeric_value2) & (input3 >= numeric_value3) {: the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Is the error in the condition of my function?

Comment: As Roland hinted, read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and http://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/134830 and update your question, or prepare for downvotes and possible closing of your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well one quick thing...the way you have your example written my.function is not a function. It may be a typo but you need to declare functions "as a function" such as:

`my.function <- function(x,y,z){  }`

Another quick point is your my.frame has the same kind of problem as your function definition again may be a typo but it looks most like you are trying to declare a vector without using a "c" as in c(1:10,11:20), but I know that's not what you are trying to do. I think you want a data.frame in that case:

`my.frame <- data.frame(a=1:10,b=11:20,c=21:30,d=31:40)`

Finally, as mentioned above you are testing a vector condition so you need a vectored conditional operator. I believe ifelse is vector(ized) too but you could just replace the & with && (two ampersands). I made the small changes to your code I mention above and it worked. Not sure what you are trying to do so it may or may not accomplish that. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

In the absence of a reproducible example, some standard pointers.  To add an extra column to a data frame based upon existing columns, you want to use `with`, `within` or `mutate` (from the `plyr` package).

`if` takes a single logical value as an input.  The warning you saw happened because you passed it a vector.  You probably want `ifelse` instead.

Comment: I have added an example function to my sample code.
If I execute the last line of code I get the following error message:
`In if((input1>=5) & (input2>=15) & (input3>=35)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`
How do I exchange this to ifelse?

Comment: Start by reading the help page, `?ifelse`, and running the examples, `example(ifelse)`.  You may also want to read the `?Logic` help page.